# Best practices for securing open APIs from quota theft

Tags: http, oauth, api

I know that `appKey` is not a means of authenticating applications. But I am wondering what are the best practices for avoiding quota theft for open APIs, that are not associated with any user account. Google Maps API could be one such example of these APIs. Including the `appKey` inside the clients (browser application, mobile clients) make them vulnerable to `appKey` theft.

For the reference, here are Google's recommendations: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037

It could be a wrong assessment, but is OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials flow with a proxy server suitable in such scenarios? Are there any real-world cases?

Comment: Why not simply encrypt your appkey when storing it?

Comment: Yes... That doesn't make it a problem at all... Good one.

Comment: @Limit Where is the decryption key stored? What about MITM?

Comment: @Noir Ah! Yes. My solution goes out of the window :P

Comment: @AndréBorie usually you SLA with third party apps, that limits the number of API calls, lets per day. AppKey theft causes the actual client to suffer too. But spikes should be allowed, as some services need them

Comment: @zeronone if you have an SLA this means you should provide apps with a minimum amount of requests they are guaranteed to be able to make. I don't see who will complain if you give them extra (or unlimited) requests. If your infrastructure is overloaded you won't be able to fulfill your SLA anyway, and if the infrastructure is fine then a quota isn't needed and you can just let everyone use the API as much as they want.

Comment: "proxy" the api over a server you control to limit/rate limit/authenticate/log/reformat/censor as needed.

Comment: @dandavis that would only be possible if there is a user-session, or some sort of authentication mechanism in the client app.

Comment: there's no auth needed unless you need it, but it's usually a good idea to launder the private APIs your app uses to protect the API keys and get logging, if nothing else. all you do is have the client talk your proxy instead of the 3rd-party API; shouldn't be more than a half-dozen LOCs.

Comment: @dandavis without any auth, it wouldn't stop anyone else making a request (even without an appKey).

Comment: in one sense, you're right that proxy won't automatically protect rates, but you can rate limit by IP, cookie, or app secret if needed (w/o auth), or just cut off the API if you're going close to the limit so as to avoid fines. No matter how you slice it, a proxy gives you _much_ more control than passing API keys to anon clients.

Comment: @dandavis It might be a wrong assessment, but can OAuth2.0 Client credentials flow be used in such situations?

Comment: if you wanted to mandate your own per-user quota, having users log in with OAuth would be one way to enforce that. there are less-bothersome ways with just cookies/IPs, but using some kind of auth would ultimately be less abuse-able by strangers.

Comment: @dandavis OAuth 2.0 client credentials doesnt require user authentication

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot setup user accounts or any other way of identification, which is best practice for every API, you are left with the following:

- Collecting metrics of number of requests per IP, Subnet, AS, Country
- Throttling proportionally to the usage while trying best effort not to compromise users who do not abuse the system and providing enough quota to the subnet, AS, country etc. This is because without user identification you will always be unfair when trying to limit by network addresses, as this bit is not identifying any user.

You might need to know what the limits should be by looking at the total number of requests from the country and also on the subnets from the same country, same for AS, subnets etc. This is to provide the best quality service by taking into account these metrics.
However this is bad method.

ps. You should really do this per user account. If the account is stolen, you put the policy on the accounts to make it not happen again. Use encryption and so on.

Comment: Again, you should really think whether a quota makes sense. If API requests are so lightweight (or they can be cached) then you'll spend more money implementing quotas that they'll actually save you.

Comment: Cache is not the infosec part.